# PyXB with XML schema containing choice statement

Tags: python, xml

i am using pyXB for binding XML.

my schema used at there has choice elements.

so when i convert XML into a python instance

i don't know exactly which element is chosen at choice element.

So in order to distinguish, i have had to use if/else statement considering all cases.

for example, if the choice element has a and b, to distinguish one within a and b

```
A = binder.CreateFromDocument(xml)  #bind into a python instance

#At this point, i don't know which element is included
#So I have to check using if/else  
if A.a:
   #processing in the case of a
   A.a.aa = 'a'
else if A.b:
   #processing in the case of b
   A.b.bb = 'b'
```

the example is so simple and if/else looks enough but if the choice element has so many element about more than 100.

that processing(repeated if/else) will be so bad.

is there any other way to know which element is chosen?

Answer (score 0):

Yes; there is a method [orderedContent](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/api/pyxb.binding.basis.complexTypeDefinition-class.html#orderedContent) on complex type instances that can be used to determine what elements are present in the instance.  This can also be used to recover the document order of elements when order is not enforced by the schema, as described [in the user documentation](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/userref_usebind.html#influencing-element-and-mixed-content-order).

Note that the members of the orderedContent list are wrapped in objects that provide information about them, so to get the underlying content binding you have to drill down through the wrapper's [value](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/api/pyxb.binding.basis._Content-class.html#value) property.